# extra partition on new laptop

Tags: 16.04, partitioning

Just picked up a new laptop and found an extra terrabyte partition on it that wasn't on the original listing ( bought on ebay ).

Was just curious if there was any reason not to use this extra partition for storage?

When I mounted the partition and attempted to add a random test file it expected me to be root , so thought I would double check before making any other changes.

[image]

Comment: That's *looks like* the Windows Recovery partition.  Above duplicate will help you assigning it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

It should be save to use it as a storage. But you can simply format it to a filesystem you like.

The program you have the screenshot of should be able to do this. Otherwise download gparted or use the command line with something like mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb

You probably need root because it is not mounted correctly

Comment: I was thinking about using this as an extra storage area, but wanted to verify there was no danger in using it as so.  

According to the image above, the entire partition is labeled as "Linux filesystem" and the only thing inside of the partition is the dir "lost+found"

It requires me to be root in order to do anything with the partition , so i wanted to verify that there was no danger in moving files into and out of it.